# How to plot nested/multi layer json dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, nested

I've been going through hours of research just to try to solve this seemingly simple issue. I'm not sure why it's been so hard to try to find. I'm trying to plot the stock data of aapl. When i extract the data from ameritrade, its a nested json dictionary. I came from matlab and found this very simple in matlab, but I am not sure how to extract the nested json out. I used pd.read_json to extract the first json but then there is still one left inside the dataframe that has data i need to plot. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is what they look like:
`df = pd.read_json(aapldata)`
And the df looks like this, I'm trying to extract the data within the 'candles' column.

#### Dataframe Picture Showing Candle Column

[image: dataframe picture showing candle column]

Answer (score 0):

As long as there is only one level of nesting, you should be able to do this :

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df = json_normalize(aapldata)
```

[source](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I tried that and am getting an error because the 'aapldata' is a string. ```AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'```. This is what my aapldata looks like plain: ```{
"candles": [
       {
           "open": 0.355178575,
           "high": 0.35535715,
           "low": 0.339285725,
           "close": 0.348214275,
           "volume": 186054400,
           "datetime": 996814800000
       },``` I also tried ```from flatten_json import flatten``` and ```flatten(aapldata)``` and gives me an error: ```flatten requires a dictionary input```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to working with json and dictionaries.